# Is there a way to cache KMS data keys using the Ruby AWS sdk?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-kms, aws-sdk-ruby

I am using the Ruby AWS SDK with Rails. Does the SDK provide a way to cache KMS data keys? I'd like to lessen the requests to KMS to improve app performance.